# Node/javascript script for setting GitHub actions secrets in bulk through GitHub APIs

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, github-actions

I’m building a simple automated deploy pipeline for learning purposes. One of the steps I’d like to implement would be setting the GitHub Actions secrets in bulk.

One of the possibilities I thought about would be to create a node script (javascript) and run before deploy. Something like: `set-secrets.js`

**Example:** I’d like to start the script with something like:

```js
// Replace these values with your own.
const REPO_OWNER = 'your-username';
const REPO_NAME = 'your-repo';
const GITHUB_TOKEN = 'your-personal-access-token';
```

And the data structure would be like:

```js
// Data structure for setting the secrets.
const arrSecrets = [];
arrSecrets.push(['KEY_NAME1', 'secretValue1']);
arrSecrets.push(['KEY_NAME2', 'secretValue2']);
// I will have more values here, but I just want an example.
```

Then loop through the arrSecrets array and set/update the GitHub Actions secrets through GitHub API.

Would that be possible? If so, anyone has an example of how I could accomplish it? I tried already with a bash .sh but got stuck.

**Constraints:**

- Node version 12 and up;
  Note: If not possible, any node version.
- Has to work on Windows and Linux/Unix/Mac (OS agnostic);
- I would like the script to overwrite a potential existing github actions secret key, if there is already one in place;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to land on a satisfying solution. It sets the github actions repo secrets key/value in bulk. Very useful for project with tons of environment variables.

```js
const { Octokit } = require("@octokit/rest");
const sodium = require('libsodium-wrappers');

Replace these values with your own.
const GITHUB_USER = 'your-username';
const GITHUB_REPO_NAME = 'your-repo';
const GITHUB_TOKEN = 'your-personal-access-token';

// Secrets.
const arrSecrets = [];
arrSecrets.push(['KEY_NAME1', 'secretValue1']);
arrSecrets.push(['KEY_NAME2', 'secretValue2']);
// Add more.

// Oktakit.
const octokit = new Octokit({
  auth: GITHUB_TOKEN
});

(async () => {
  const { data: { key, key_id } } = await octokit.actions.getRepoPublicKey({
    owner: GITHUB_USER,
    repo: GITHUB_REPO_NAME
  });

  // Loop through the key/value arrays.
  arrSecrets.forEach(async ([secretKey, secretValue]) => {
    // Encrypt secret value.
    await sodium.ready;

    // Convert the secret and key to a Uint8Array.
    const binkey = sodium.from_base64(key, sodium.base64_variants.ORIGINAL);
    const binsec = sodium.from_string(secretValue);

    // Encrypt the secret using libsodium.
    const encBytes = sodium.crypto_box_seal(binsec, binkey);

    // Convert the encrypted Uint8Array to Base64.
    secretValueEncrypted = sodium.to_base64(encBytes, sodium.base64_variants.ORIGINAL);

    // Set secret.
    await octokit.request(`PUT /repos/${ GITHUB_USER}/${ GITHUB_REPO_NAME}/actions/secrets/${secretKey}`, {
        owner: GITHUB_USER,
        repo: GITHUB_REPO_NAME,
        secret_name: secretKey,
        encrypted_value: secretValueEncrypted,
        key_id: key_id,
        headers: {
          'X-GitHub-Api-Version': '2022-11-28'
      }
    });    
  });
})();
```

References:

- https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/v20
- https://docs.github.com/en/rest/guides/encrypting-secrets-for-the-rest-api?apiVersion=2022-11-28
- https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/secrets?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-or-update-a-repository-secret

There’s even room to load your local file `.env` variables and set them all in bulk at once.